# Laravel - How to get data that not exist in another table with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 table "phones" and "logs". I want to get phone number that not in "logs" table with client id = 1.

this my code:

```
DB::table('phones')
->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($request) {
      $query->select(DB::raw(1))
      ->from('log')
      ->whereRaw('mn.phone = cln.phone');
      ->where('log.client_id', '!=', $request->client_id);
    })
```

with above code success to get phone number that not in "logs" table, but the `->where('log.client_id', '!=', $request->client_id)` condition not working, it will exclude all phone number in "logs" table. How to get get phone number that in logs table with client_id = 2?

Logs Table

[image]

Phones Table

[image]

Comment: it would be easier if you store phone_id in the logs table instead phone column

Comment: @EmtiazZahid yeah but that is not my project from scrath, i just continue someone project